# why li marker is not aligning center in ul/ol li inside div element?

Tags: html, css

why li marker is not aligning center in ul/ol li inside div element?

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
      <li>hello world</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the lorem ipsum text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the markers inside the `li` space by adding `list-style-position: inside` to your `ul`.

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
}

ul{
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
      <li>hello world</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How to align texts equally to the right when texts come to a new line on resizing. Pls the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/harishlovestocode/p8tsfhkz/5/

Answer (score 1):

check the width of your `ul`, `li`.
Better use `display: flex` for your div, set `justify-content: center` or `align-items: center;`

Comment: How to align texts equally to the right when texts come to a new line on resizing. Pls the code here: jsfiddle.net/harishlovestocode/p8tsfhkz/5